# Object seems split into two

Tags: modeling, mesh, normals

my object is split into two. Last time I got rid of this problem by making normals consistent, but this time it doesnt work. I have a Mirror Modifier on the objecgt, but not applied yet.
Thanks for your help!
[image]

Comment: Maybe the body of your character has faces on the inside (along the mirror axis) : deactivate the mirror modifier and make sure to delete those faces if any. Or, maybe there is a small gap beetwen the vertices of each side (the vertices aren't perfectly along the axis) : try to increase the Merge Limit value.

Comment: thanks for your answer :) sadly i already applied subdivision surface, but nothing seemed to be wrong with the mesh. By incresing the merge Limit nothing happened :( will those different meshes be visible when applying a texture or is nothing going to change? bc then i would leave it like that

Comment: You should have specified that you used a Subdivision Surface. I Suspect that when you applied it, it was BEFORE the mirror in the modifier stack ; that's a common issue. Anyway, why did you applied it ? Feel free to post your .blend if you want me to check it.

Comment: oh yes, i remember that issue. yes i would love to! can I add it in here and do you think you can fix it?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/wn3d5w63ub0oii6/robotercleanedauseinander.blend?dl=0 this should be the file

Answer (score 1):

Your mesh is a nightmare to edit, because you applied the SubSurf modifier. You shouldn't do that unless you've got a good reason !

So first, we will Un-subdivide it. You can add a Decimate modifier, select the Un-Subdivide mode, and choose a Iteration of 10. Feel free to play with that value, 10 looks like a good compromise :
[image]

You can now Apply this modifier ; this way, you'll get a mesh that is largely easier to Edit.
[image]

The next step is to add a Subdivision modifier again, so the mesh will look smoother. A Level of 2 or 3 is more than enough.

For the mesh to look even smoother, but without adding more faces, you can go in the Object menu and select Shade Smooth.

[image]

There is still some pinches, but now you can move vertices in Edit Mode to mitigate them. Anyway due to the bad topology on the highlighted zone, you won't have a perfect result :
[image]

I would suggest to read this [Topology Guide](https://topologyguides.com/6-tips-for-subdivision-modeling) (the whole site is quite interesting) if you want to improve this useful skill.